# Issue in generating node_module

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have an issue with `yarn`. After runnit `yarn init -y` it is not generating node_modlues,
I am runnig `yarn 3.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` is only created when you install something, like with

```bash
yarn add zod
```

Comment: after installing it is not creating